# Finding points on curves in HTML 5 2d Canvas context

Tags: html, canvas, bezier

Given lines drawn by 2d canvas context functions `bezierCurveTo`, `quadraticCurveTo` or `arcTo`, how can I find points along those lines?

My intent is to draw an object at the midpoint of a curve.  Using the SVG DOM, I can do this with methods `getPointAtLength` & `getTotalLength`, but I can't see an equivalent in HTML canvas.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You find them the hard way :(

There isn't an equivalent in HTML canvas. You have to find the midpoints yourself with plain old math.

I did an example of how to find midpoint of bezier curves for you. Real curve is red, midpoint is the tiny green rectangle. Everything else is just a visual aid.

```js
var ctx = test.getContext("2d")

function mid(a,b) {
 return (a+b) / 2;
}


var cp1x = 100;
var cp1y = 150;
var cp2x = 175;
var cp2y = 175;
var x = 200;
var y = 0;

ctx.lineWidth = 4;
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,0,0,0.6)";

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(cp1x, cp1y, cp2x, cp2y, x, y);
ctx.stroke();

//line goes from start to control point 1
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(0,0,200,0.4)";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(0, 0);
ctx.lineTo(cp1x , cp1y);
ctx.stroke();

//line goes from end to control point 2
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(x, y);
ctx.lineTo(cp2x , cp2y);
ctx.stroke();

//line goes from control point to control point
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(200,0,200,0.4)";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(cp1x, cp1y);
ctx.lineTo(cp2x , cp2y);
ctx.stroke();

// now find the midpoint of each of those 3 lines
var ax = mid(cp1x,0);
var bx = mid(cp2x,x)
var cx = mid(cp1x,cp2x)

var ay = mid(cp1y,0)    
var by = mid(cp2y,y)    
var cy = mid(cp1y,cp2y)

    
// draw midpoints for visual aid 
// not gonna look exact 'cause square
// will be drawn from top-right instead of center
ctx.fillRect(ax, ay, 4, 4);
ctx.fillRect(bx, by, 4, 4);
ctx.fillRect(cx, cy, 4, 4);


//now draw lines between those three points. These are green
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(0,200,0,0.4)";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(ax, ay);
ctx.lineTo(cx , cy);
ctx.stroke();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(bx, by);
ctx.lineTo(cx , cy);
ctx.stroke();

//now the midpoint of the green lines:
// so g1 and g2 are the green line midpoints
var g1x = mid(ax,cx);
var g2x = mid(bx,cx);

var g1y = mid(ay,cy); 
var g2y = mid(by,cy);  

//draw them to make sure:
ctx.fillRect(g1x , g1y, 4, 4);
ctx.fillRect(g2x , g2y, 4, 4);

//now one final line, in gray
ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(20,20,20,0.4)";
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(g1x , g1y);
ctx.lineTo(g2x , g2y);
ctx.stroke();
 
//whew! We made it!
var FinallyTheMidpointx = mid(g1x,g2x); 
var FinallyTheMidpointy = mid(g1y,g2y); 

//draw something at the midpoint to celebrate
ctx.fillStyle = "rgba(0,255,0,1)";
ctx.fillRect(FinallyTheMidpointx, FinallyTheMidpointy, 4, 4);
```

```html
<canvas id="test" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```

Comment: Wow! That is way beyond helpful.  All I was looking for was for someone to confirm the existence or absence of an easy way, before I crack on and do it the hard way.

Comment: Note that this is the midpoint with respect to the Bezier input parameter, not the midpoint of the curve itself (you've simply found the on-curve point for t=0.5 using de Casteljau's algorithm). If you want the midpoint of the _curve_, you'll need to do something rather different, i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/a/76773275/740553

Answer (score 2):

One thing to remember is that even if you're drawing things on the canvas, you can still use SVG to do the maths for you: you can create a path element (using `createElementNS`, not `createElement`. SVG elements are unfortunately still considered special, despite SVG being considered "part of HTML5" ever since that replaced HTML4.01) and then use its length functions to help you do what you want to do.

with that said...

#### Finding the midpoint of an `arcTo` curve

For an arc with identical major and minor radius, e.g. a circular arc, this is trivial: get the half angle between your start and end angles, and then you just compute the coordinate using the parametric circle formula:

```js
const { sin, cos } = Math;
const angle = (startAngle + endAngle)/2;
const midpoint = {
  x: cx + r * cos(angle),
  y: cy + r * sin(angle),
};
```

For an *elliptical* arc things are *much* harder, because there is [no "simple" formula for computing a point, given a distance along the curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral). There are two common ways to work around that, though:

1. find the approximate midpoint, using a lookup table ("LUT"), or
2. find the midpoint using a binary search

###### using a LUT

In the LUT approach you build a table with [a number of points on the curve](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22064/calculating-a-point-that-lies-on-an-ellipse-given-an-angle) with some regularly spaced out angle from start to end angle, and then compute the lengths at each coordinate to get a table like:

| angle | x | y | length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| s + (e-s) * 0.0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| s + (e-s) * 0.1 | 10 | 5 | 3.9 |
| s + (e-s) * 0.2 | 20 | 17 | 8.7 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| s + (e-s) * 0.9 | 150 | 150 | 25.3 |
| s + (e-s) * 1.0 | 152 | 140 | 27 |

You can then use to find the two coordinates nearest your target distance. For the midpoint, your target is `length(e) / 2`, which for this table means finding the two points closest to `angle = 27/2 = 13.5`.

If you're *extremely lucky* there is a point with that exact length, but the overwhelming majority of cases involve one coordinate `p1` with a length less than, and one coordinate `p2` with a length greater than your target length, and you interpolate between those two points.

```js
const target = LUT.at(-1).len / 2
const [p1, p2] = findNearest(LUT, target);
const { len: l1, angle: a1 } = p1;
const { len: l2, angle: a2 } = p2;
const ratio = (target - l1) / (l2 - l1)
const midpointAngle = lerp(ratio, a1, a2);
```

(Where `lerp` is the standard linear interpolation function `(ratio, a, b) => (1-ratio) * a + ratio * b`, with ratio some value from 0 to 1)

Now that we have the approximate angle, we can directly compute where on our elliptical arc our midpoint, with the formula for calculating a point given the ellipse parameters (center, radii, and angle) easily found.

###### Using a binary search

Binary searching is the process of "repeating the same check over and over until we're close enough that more precision is irrelevant for what we need".

Compute the total length of your arc (which you already know how to do: define a path that is *just* your arc, then get its total length), then:

1. set "target" to totalLength /2
2. set "low" to your start angle
3. set "high" to your end angle
4. set "mid" to (low + high) / 2
5. create a new arc that runs from start to mid, and measure its length
6. If that length is close enough to your target, stop.
7. If we get here and the length is:

   1. less than your target, set low = mid
   2. greater than your target, set high = mid
8. rerun from step 4

With the deciding factor being step 6: you get to decide what "close enough" means (i.e. less than 1 off? less then 0.1? 0.01? etc)

At the end of that, your `mid` value will be the midpoint angle, and you again now just compute the midpoint coordinate directly.

###### Which do I use?

It depends on how often you need to find points on your curve based on distance. If you just need the midpoint, once, then you probably want a binary search. However, if you need multiple points at different distances, possibly even at different distances at different times over the curve's lifetime, then a LUT might offer better performance, at the cost of precision.

#### Finding the midpoint of a Bezier curve (both quadratic and cubic)

Getting the midpoint of the curve's *input* parameter is trivial, it's `t=0.5` and then you just compute the `x` and `y` values for your curve using the standard Bezier function:

```js
function computeQuadratic(t, a,b,c) {
  const mt = 1-t
  return (a*mt*mt) + (2*b*mt*t) + (c*t*t);
}

function computeCubic(t, a,b,c,d) {
  const mt = 1-t, t2 = t*t, mt2 = mt*mt;
  return (a*mt2*mt) + (3*b*mt2*t) + (3*c*mt*t2) + (d*t2*t);
}
```

where a, b, c, and d are your curve's control values for the x or y dimension, i.e.:

```js
const quadraticPoint = {
  x: computeQuadratic(t, x1, x2, x3),
  y: computeQuadratic(t, y1, y2, y3),
}

// or

const cubicPoint = {
  x: computeCubic(t, x1, x2, x3, x4),
  y: computeCubic(t, y1, y2, y3, y4),
}
```

However, that won't get you the midpoint of the curve itself, which can be *wildly* far away from input midpoint. So we're back to the same problem that the elliptical arc had: either use the LUT approach, or use a binary search.

For Beziers you'd create a LUT with `t` from 0 to 1, e.g:

| t | x | y | length |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0.1 | 10 | 5 | 3.9 |
| 0.2 | 20 | 17 | 8.7 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 0.9 | 150 | 150 | 25.3 |
| 1.0 | 152 | 140 | 27 |

And then the procedure's the same: find the closest coordinates and `lerp` to find the approximate `t` value for the true midpoint, which we can directly calculate:

```js
const midpoint = {
  x: computeQuadratic(t, x1,x2,x3),
  y: computeQuadratic(t, y1,y2,y3),
}

// or

const midpoint = {
  x: computeCubic(t, x1,x2,x3,x4),
  y: computeCubic(t, y1,y2,y3,y4),
}
```

With the binary search steps being similar, too:

1. set "target" to totalLength/2
2. set "low" to 0
3. set "high" to 1
4. set "mid" to (low + high) / 2
5. create a new bezier curve path that runs from start to mid (getting the coordinates for that by [splitting the curve at `t=mid`](https://pomax.github.io/bezierjs/#split), and measuring the length.
6. If that length is close enough to your target, stop.
7. If we get here and the length is:

   1. less than your target, set low = mid
   2. greater than your target, set high = mid
8. rerun from step 5

When this stops, `mid` is our midpoint `t` value and we directly compute the coordinate as above.

Answer (score 1):

A Bezier Curve is calculated Mathematically with this formula
[image: Bezier Curve Mathematically]
Where P0 is the startpoint, P1 and P2 are the control points and P3 is the end point.

To calculate the halfwaypoint you can just use `t = 0.5`.

Similar for the Quadratic Curve:
[image: Quadratic Curve Mathematically]

[Source and further Information](http://www.independent-software.com/determining-coordinates-on-a-html-canvas-bezier-curve.html)

Comment: This is _quite_ wrong: `t=0.5` is the _input domain_ midpoint, not the curve's midpoint. Because elliptical arcs and bezier curves are non-linear with respect to their input, the only time that `t=0.5` is the actual curve midpoint is when we're dealing with curves that are symmetrical about the input midpoint, which will only be true for a _tiny_ fraction of cases.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by [Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570309/finding-points-on-curves-in-html-5-2d-canvas-context/76773275#76773275): the point for `t=0.5` calculated by de Casteljau's algorithm is not equal to the the point at `pathlength/2` unless the path is symmetrical.

If you can't use native browser methods like `SVGGeometryElement.getpointAtlength()`, e.g. because you're developing a Node.js application, you might try the [svg-path-properties](https://github.com/rveciana/svg-path-properties) library, which aims to replicate methods like `getTotalLength()` and `getPointAtLength()`.

#### Browser method `getPointAtLength()` vs. library replacement

`new svgPathProperties.svgPathProperties(d)`, expects the path `d` string to as an argument to retrieve its properties such as `getTotalLength()` and `getPointAtLength()`.

##### Main challenge: elliptic Arcs

Currently, svg-path-properties seems to struggle with elliptic arcs
(rx != ry – see W3c spec: [The elliptical arc curve commands](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG2/paths.html#PathDataEllipticalArcCommands) ).

Circular arcs and all other command types (`l`,`h`,`v`,`c`,`s`,`q`,`t`) work pretty fine ([see codepen demo](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/LYXvzpd)).

```js
// elliptic arc - not working!
let mid1 = getMidPoint(path1.getAttribute("d"), 0.5);
renderPoint(
  svg1,
  path1.getPointAtLength(path1.getTotalLength() * 0.5),
  "green",
  "3%"
);
renderPoint(svg1, mid1, "red", "2%");

// elliptic arc, converted to cubic beziers -  working!
let d2 = path2.getAttribute("d");
d2 = ellipticArcsToCubicInD(d2);

let mid2 = getMidPoint(d2, 0.5);
let midN1 = path1.getPointAtLength(path2.getTotalLength() * 0.5);
renderPoint(svg2, midN1, "green", "3%");
renderPoint(svg2, mid2, "red", "2%");

function getMidPoint(d, length = 0.5) {
  let pathProperties = new svgPathProperties.svgPathProperties(d);
  let pathLength = pathProperties.getTotalLength();
  let ptMid = pathProperties.getPointAtLength(pathLength * length);
  return ptMid;
}

/**
 * convert ellipctic arctos
 * returns d pathdata string
 */
function ellipticArcsToCubicInD(d) {
  let hasArcs = /a/gi.test(d);
  let hasRel = /[astvzqmhlc]/g.test(d);
  let hasShorthands = /[hstv]/gi.test(d);

  /**
   * check if pathdata contains elliptic arcs
   * skip otherwise conversion
   */
  if (!hasArcs) {
    return d;
  }

  // parse d to pathData array
  let pathData = getPathData(d);
  if (hasArcs) {
    // convert to all absolute
    let pathDataFixed = hasRel ? pathDataToAbsolute(pathData) : pathData;
    // convert shorthands
    pathDataFixed = hasShorthands ? pathDataToLonghands(pathDataFixed) : pathData;
    // convert elliptic arcs
    pathDataFixed = pathDataConvertEllipticArcs(pathDataFixed);
    d = pathDataToD(pathDataFixed);
  }

  return d;
}

/**
 * Based on: jkroso/parse-svg-path
 * https://github.com/jkroso/parse-svg-path
 * parse an svg path data string. Generates an Array
 * of commands where each command is an Array of the
 * form `{type:command, values:[]}`
 */
function getPathData(path) {
  // expected argument lengths
  var length = {
    a: 7,
    c: 6,
    h: 1,
    l: 2,
    m: 2,
    q: 4,
    s: 4,
    t: 2,
    v: 1,
    z: 0
  };
  // segment pattern
  var segment = /([astvzqmhlc])([^astvzqmhlc]*)/gi;
  var number = /-?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+(?:e[-+]?\d+)?/gi;
  var data = [];
  const parseValues = (args) => {
    var numbers = args.match(number);
    return numbers ? numbers.map(Number) : [];
  };
  // split adjacent zero values like 0 05 => 0 0 5
  path = path.replace(/( )(0)(\d+)/g, "$1 $2 $3");
  path.replace(segment, function(_, command, args) {
    var type = command.toLowerCase();
    args = parseValues(args);
    // overloaded moveTo
    if (type == "m" && args.length > 2) {
      data.push([command].concat(args.splice(0, 2)));
      type = "l";
      command = command == "m" ? "l" : "L";
    }
    while (true) {
      if (args.length == length[type]) {
        //args.unshift(command)
        let values = args.splice(0, length[type]);
        return data.push({
          type: command,
          values: values
        });
      }
      if (args.length < length[type]) throw new Error("malformed path data");
    }
  });
  return data;
}

function pathDataToAbsolute(pathData) {
  let x = 0,
    y = 0,
    mx = 0,
    my = 0;
  for (let cmd of pathData) {
    let type = cmd.type.toUpperCase();
    let values = cmd.values;

    if (type !== cmd.type) {
      cmd.type = type;

      if (type === "A") {
        values[5] += x;
        values[6] += y;
      } else if (type === "V") {
        values[0] += y;
      } else if (type === "H") {
        values[0] += x;
      } else if (type === "M") {
        [mx, my] = values;
        mx += x;
        my += y;
      } else if (values.length) {
        for (let v = 0; v < values.length; v++) {
          values[v] += v % 2 ? y : x;
        }
      }
    }

    const vLen = values.length;
    if (type === "Z") {
      x = mx;
      y = my;
    } else if (type === "H") {
      x = values[0];
    } else if (type === "V") {
      y = values[0];
    } else if (type === "M") {
      [x, y] = values.slice(-2);
    } else {
      x = values[vLen - 2];
      y = values[vLen - 1];
    }
  }

  return pathData;
}

/**
 * decompose/convert shorthands to "longhand" commands:
 * H, V, S, T => L, L, C, Q
 * reversed method: pathDataToShorthands()
 */
function pathDataToLonghands(pathData) {
  let pathDataLonghand = [];
  let comPrev = {
    type: "M",
    values: pathData[0].values
  };
  pathDataLonghand.push(comPrev);
  for (let i = 1; i < pathData.length; i++) {
    let com = pathData[i];
    let type = com.type;
    let values = com.values;
    let valuesL = values.length;
    let valuesPrev = comPrev.values;
    let valuesPrevL = valuesPrev.length;
    let [x, y] = [values[valuesL - 2], values[valuesL - 1]];
    let cp1X, cp1Y, cpN1X, cpN1Y, cpN2X, cpN2Y, cp2X, cp2Y;
    let [prevX, prevY] = [
      valuesPrev[valuesPrevL - 2],
      valuesPrev[valuesPrevL - 1]
    ];
    switch (type) {
      case "H":
        comPrev = {
          type: "L",
          values: [values[0], prevY]
        };
        break;
      case "V":
        comPrev = {
          type: "L",
          values: [prevX, values[0]]
        };
        break;
      case "T":
        [cp1X, cp1Y] = [valuesPrev[0], valuesPrev[1]];
        [prevX, prevY] = [
          valuesPrev[valuesPrevL - 2],
          valuesPrev[valuesPrevL - 1]
        ];
        // new control point
        cpN1X = prevX + (prevX - cp1X);
        cpN1Y = prevY + (prevY - cp1Y);
        comPrev = {
          type: "Q",
          values: [cpN1X, cpN1Y, x, y]
        };
        break;
      case "S":
        [cp1X, cp1Y] = [valuesPrev[0], valuesPrev[1]];
        [cp2X, cp2Y] =
        valuesPrevL > 2 ? [valuesPrev[2], valuesPrev[3]] : [valuesPrev[0], valuesPrev[1]];
        [prevX, prevY] = [
          valuesPrev[valuesPrevL - 2],
          valuesPrev[valuesPrevL - 1]
        ];
        // new control points
        cpN1X = 2 * prevX - cp2X;
        cpN1Y = 2 * prevY - cp2Y;
        cpN2X = values[0];
        cpN2Y = values[1];
        comPrev = {
          type: "C",
          values: [cpN1X, cpN1Y, cpN2X, cpN2Y, x, y]
        };
        break;
      default:
        comPrev = {
          type: type,
          values: values
        };
    }
    pathDataLonghand.push(comPrev);
  }
  return pathDataLonghand;
}
/**
 * convert arc commands to cubic
 * Based on: Dmitry Baranovskiy's
 * https://github.com/DmitryBaranovskiy/raphael/blob/v2.1.1/dev/raphael.core.js#L1837
 */
function arcCommandToCubic(p0, comValues, recursive = false) {
  if (Array.isArray(p0)) {
    p0 = {
      x: p0[0],
      y: p0[1]
    };
  }
  let [r1, r2, angle, largeArcFlag, sweepFlag, x2, y2] = comValues;
  let [x1, y1] = [p0.x, p0.y];
  const degToRad = (degrees) => {
    return (Math.PI * degrees) / 180;
  };
  const rotate = (x, y, angleRad) => {
    let X = x * Math.cos(angleRad) - y * Math.sin(angleRad);
    let Y = x * Math.sin(angleRad) + y * Math.cos(angleRad);
    return {
      x: X,
      y: Y
    };
  };
  let angleRad = degToRad(angle);
  let params = [];
  let x, y, f1, f2, cx, cy, h;
  if (recursive) {
    f1 = recursive[0];
    f2 = recursive[1];
    cx = recursive[2];
    cy = recursive[3];
  } else {
    let p1 = rotate(x1, y1, -angleRad);
    x1 = p1.x;
    y1 = p1.y;
    let p2 = rotate(x2, y2, -angleRad);
    x2 = p2.x;
    y2 = p2.y;
    x = (x1 - x2) / 2;
    y = (y1 - y2) / 2;
    h = (x * x) / (r1 * r1) + (y * y) / (r2 * r2);
    if (h > 1) {
      h = Math.sqrt(h);
      r1 = h * r1;
      r2 = h * r2;
    }
    let sign = largeArcFlag === sweepFlag ? -1 : 1;
    let r1Pow = r1 * r1;
    let r2Pow = r2 * r2;
    let left = r1Pow * r2Pow - r1Pow * y * y - r2Pow * x * x;
    let right = r1Pow * y * y + r2Pow * x * x;
    let k = sign * Math.sqrt(Math.abs(left / right));
    cx = (k * r1 * y) / r2 + (x1 + x2) / 2;
    cy = (k * -r2 * x) / r1 + (y1 + y2) / 2;
    f1 = Math.asin(parseFloat(((y1 - cy) / r2).toFixed(9)));
    f2 = Math.asin(parseFloat(((y2 - cy) / r2).toFixed(9)));
    if (x1 < cx) {
      f1 = Math.PI - f1;
    }
    if (x2 < cx) {
      f2 = Math.PI - f2;
    }
    if (f1 < 0) {
      f1 = Math.PI * 2 + f1;
    }
    if (f2 < 0) {
      f2 = Math.PI * 2 + f2;
    }
    if (sweepFlag && f1 > f2) {
      f1 = f1 - Math.PI * 2;
    }
    if (!sweepFlag && f2 > f1) {
      f2 = f2 - Math.PI * 2;
    }
  }
  let df = f2 - f1;
  if (Math.abs(df) > (Math.PI * 120) / 180) {
    let f2old = f2;
    let x2old = x2;
    let y2old = y2;
    f2 =
      sweepFlag && f2 > f1 ?
      (f2 = f1 + ((Math.PI * 120) / 180) * 1) :
      (f2 = f1 + ((Math.PI * 120) / 180) * -1);
    x2 = cx + r1 * Math.cos(f2);
    y2 = cy + r2 * Math.sin(f2);
    params = arcCommandToCubic(
      [x2, y2], [r1, r2, angle, 0, sweepFlag, x2old, y2old], [f2, f2old, cx, cy]
    );
  }
  df = f2 - f1;
  let c1 = Math.cos(f1);
  let s1 = Math.sin(f1);
  let c2 = Math.cos(f2);
  let s2 = Math.sin(f2);
  let t = Math.tan(df / 4);
  let hx = (4 / 3) * r1 * t;
  let hy = (4 / 3) * r2 * t;
  let m1 = [x1, y1];
  let m2 = [x1 + hx * s1, y1 - hy * c1];
  let m3 = [x2 + hx * s2, y2 - hy * c2];
  let m4 = [x2, y2];
  m2[0] = 2 * m1[0] - m2[0];
  m2[1] = 2 * m1[1] - m2[1];
  if (recursive) {
    return [m2, m3, m4].concat(params);
  } else {
    params = [m2, m3, m4].concat(params);
    let commands = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < params.length; i += 3) {
      r1 = rotate(params[i][0], params[i][1], angleRad);
      r2 = rotate(params[i + 1][0], params[i + 1][1], angleRad);
      r3 = rotate(params[i + 2][0], params[i + 2][1], angleRad);
      commands.push({
        type: "C",
        values: [r1.x, r1.y, r2.x, r2.y, r3.x, r3.y]
      });
    }
    return commands;
  }
}
/**
 * normalize to all absolute, cubic, no shorthand
 */
function pathDataConvertEllipticArcs(pathData) {
  let pathDataNorm = [];
  pathData.forEach((com, i) => {
    let [type, values] = [com.type, com.values];
    let comPrev = i > 0 ? pathData[i - 1] : pathData[i];
    let valuesPrev = comPrev.values;
    let valuesPrevL = valuesPrev.length;
    let p0 = {
      x: valuesPrev[valuesPrevL - 2],
      y: valuesPrev[valuesPrevL - 1]
    };
    if (type === "A" && values[0] != values[1]) {
      let cubicArcs = arcCommandToCubic(p0, values);
      cubicArcs.forEach((cubicArc) => {
        pathDataNorm.push(cubicArc);
      });
    } else {
      pathDataNorm.push(com);
    }
  });
  return pathDataNorm;
}

// pathData to d string without optimizations
function pathDataToD(pathData) {
  let d = pathData
    .map((com) => {
      return `${com.type}${com.values.join(" ")}`;
    })
    .join("");
  return d;
}

function renderPoint(
  svg,
  coords,
  fill = "red",
  r = "2",
  opacity = "1",
  id = "",
  className = ""
) {
  if (Array.isArray(coords)) {
    coords = {
      x: coords[0],
      y: coords[1]
    };
  }
  let marker = `<circle class="${className}" opacity="${opacity}" id="${id}" cx="${coords.x}" cy="${coords.y}" r="${r}" fill="${fill}">
  <title>${coords.x} ${coords.y}</title></circle>`;
  svg.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", marker);
}
```

```css
svg {
  height: 90vmin;
  width: auto;
  overflow: visible;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

```html
<p>Green: pointAtLength native; red: svg-path-properties</p>

<svg id="svg1" viewBox="0 0 150 100">
  <path id="path1" d="M 50 0 a 50 30 22 0 1 50 75 " />
</svg>

<svg id="svg2" viewBox="0 0 150 100">
  <path id="path2" d="M 50 0 a 50 30 22 0 1 50 75 " />
</svg>


<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/svg-path-properties@1.1.0/dist/svg-path-properties.min.js"></script>
```

A (rather clunky) workaround for this problem could be to convert elliptical arcs to cubic bézier approximations – sacrificing accuracy and performance.

However, the resulting point precision as well as the impact on performance might be acceptable as long as you apply these expensive recalculations only to paths, that actually contain elliptic arcs.

Comment: It feels like this, like all the other previous answers, ignores the fact that the question was not just about bezier curves =)

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans: I don't think so =) Since the mentioned library **aims to replicate the natively supported (SVG related browser) methods** (actually pretty well ) you can drop in also Arctos, quadratic Béziers or lineTos commands – including multiple path segments to get the desired midpoint coordinates . But you're right, my answer was **too focused on Béziers** – I've added another example. Frankly, until recently I myself thought that t=0.5 was equivalent to half the path length ... until I tried non-symmetrical curves – needs more emphasis!

Comment: it's kinda basic maths. Any nonlinear function does not have its midpoint at the midpoint of its input, except under very specific conditions. But I'd recommend laying off the bold: neither the answer nor comments need it.

Comment: small note on the updated answer: the second example for arcs and lines seems to have two circular arcs, instead of one circular arc and one elliptical arc.

Comment: @Mike 'Pomax' Kamermans: svg-path-properties.js has indeed a bug concerning elliptic arcs. I filed a bug report and edited my post (including a clunky elliptic-arc-to-cubic -approximation workaround).  About the overuse of boldened/overemphasized  text ... I think we should focus on actual inaccuracies or misleading info in answers.

Comment: We can focus on all the things that matter, which includes spurious use of bold text, which will confuse readers (especially those for whom English is not their first language) more than it helps them. Present the information, without emphasis on random words, so the reader can absorb the information to the best of their ability.

Answer (score -1):

Check out http://pomax.github.io/bezierjs/

There's a bunch of handy functions there, the one you want to use is .get(t) where t=0.5

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Note that the question wasn't about t=0.5 though, but the midpoint of a curve. Because neither elliptical arcs nor Bezier curves are linear curves, the midpoint of the input parameter is typically _isn't_ the midpoint of the curve itself.