# Opposite of svg's getPointAtLength(d) - I want getLengthAtPoint(x,y)

Tags: javascript, svg

A SVGGeometryElement element has a method `SVGGeometryElement.getPointAtLength()` which returns a DomPoint object (e.g. x and y) at a distance along the path.

I want the opposite. Given an (x,y) coordinate, what is the distance along that path (assuming it intersects)? It seems like I'd have to test all points along the path until it matched/fuzzily matched the x,y target coordinates. Is there an easier way?

Comment: That may have multiple answers. What would an API return in that case? I imagine that's why you'd need to write your own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As commented by Robert Longson:
we may have *multiple* length results for a point (e.g due to self inflections like in a Moebius/infinity loop)

##### Example1: lengthAtPoint via lookup

Here is a *sloppy* approach to get something like a `lengthAtPoint` functionality:

```js
const svg = document.querySelector("svg");
const pathTmpl = document.getElementById("pathTmpl");
const strokePath = document.getElementById("stroke");

// steps for pathlength lookup
let precision = 500;
let tolerance = 10;

// create length lookup
let t0 = performance.now()
let lengthLookup = getLengthLookup(pathTmpl, precision);
let t1 = performance.now()
let t2 = t1-t0
console.log('lookup calculation:', precision+' sample points', t2, 'ms')


document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  // cursor point
  let pt = new DOMPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);

  // update cursor
  let ptSvg = screenToSVG(svg, pt);
  circle.setAttribute("cx", ptSvg.x);
  circle.setAttribute("cy", ptSvg.y);

  // update length
  let lengthAtPoint = getLengthAtPoint(lengthLookup, ptSvg);

  // demo illustration: change dasharray
  if (lengthAtPoint) {
    strokePath.setAttribute(
      "stroke-dasharray",
      `${lengthAtPoint} ${lengthLookup.pathLength}`
    );
  }
});

function getLengthAtPoint(lengthLookup, pt) {
  let lengthAtPoint = 0;
  let { lengthArr, yArr, xArr, pathLength } = lengthLookup;

  // find length
  let found = false;

  for (let i = 0; i < yArr.length && !found; i++) {
    let x = xArr[i];
    let y = yArr[i];

    // compare diviations
    let diffX = Math.abs(pt.x - x);
    let diffY = Math.abs(pt.y - y);
    let diff = (diffX + diffY) / 2;
    let diffMin = Math.min(diffX, diffY);
    let diffMax = Math.max(diffX, diffY);


    // add tolerance threshold
    let maxDiffRat = 1.5
    if (
      diff < tolerance ||
      (diffX < tolerance && diffY < tolerance * maxDiffRat) ||
      (diffY < tolerance && diffX < tolerance * maxDiffRat)
    ) {
      
      // nearest length with close x/y coordinates
      let length = lengthArr[i];
      
      /**
      * at this point you can certainly 
      * find a smarter interpolation to adjust
      * the actual path length
      */
      lengthAtPoint = (lengthArr[i]) + (diffMax);

      // stop loop
      found = true;
    } 
  }
  return lengthAtPoint;
}



/**
* create lookup containing lengths and 
* coordinates at equidistant
*/
function getLengthLookup(path, precision = 100) {
  //create pathlength lookup
  let pathLength = path.getTotalLength();
  let lengthLookup = {
    yArr: [],
    xArr: [],
    lengthArr: [],
    pathLength: pathLength
  };

  // sample point to calculate Y at pathLengths
  let step = Math.ceil(pathLength / precision);

  for (let l = 0; l < pathLength; l += step) {
    //let pt = SVGToScreen(svg, path.getPointAtLength(l));
    let pt = path.getPointAtLength(l);
    lengthLookup.xArr.push(pt.x);
    lengthLookup.yArr.push(pt.y);
    lengthLookup.lengthArr.push(l);
  }
  return lengthLookup;
}

/** Based on @Paul LeBeau's answer
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343436/how-to-convert-svg-element-coordinates-to-screen-coordinates#48354404
 */
function SVGToScreen(svg, pt) {
  let p = new DOMPoint(pt.x, pt.y);
  p = p.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM());
  return p;
}

function screenToSVG(svg, pt) {
  let p = new DOMPoint(pt.x, pt.y);
  return p.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
}
```

```css
svg {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<h3>Click on path</h3>
  
  <svg  width="543" height="7907" viewBox="0 0 543 7907" >
    <defs>
      <path fill="none" id="pathTmpl" d="M125.5 1v0c0 78.2 63.4 141.5 141.5 141.5h126.9c25.9 0 51.4 6.9 73.9 19.8v0c45.9 26.5 74.2 75.4 74.2 128.4v22.9l-2.2 20.1c-5.7 53.2-40.2 99-89.8 119.1l-25.3 10.2c-5.1 2.1-9.6 5.3-13.1 9.5v0c-5.2 6.1-8.1 13.9-8.1 22v9.7v0c0 12.8-10.4 23.3-23.3 23.3h-368.7c-5.8 0-10.5 4.7-10.5 10.5v0v405.5v0c0 5.8 4.7 10.5 10.5 10.5h378v0c7.7 0 14 6.3 14 14v384.3v762.9c0 34.2-27.8 62-62 62v0c-34.2 0-62 27.7-62 62v180.8c0 7.2-5.8 13-13 13v0h-249.5c-6.6 0-12 5.4-12 12v0v400v0c0 8.8 7.2 16 16 16h245.5v0c7.2 0 13 5.8 13 13v1129.6c0 53.9-43.8 97.7-97.7 97.7v0c-54 0-97.8 43.8-97.8 97.8v133.4v0c0 3.3 2.7 6 6 6h92.5v0c3.3 0 6 2.7 6 6v417.5c0 2.8-2.2 5-5 5v0h-92.5c-3.9 0-7 3.1-7 7v0v331.7c0 77.8 63.1 141 141 141h36.2c57.9 0 104.8 46.9 104.8 104.8v0v104.5v0c0 7.5-6 13.5-13.5 13.5h-240c-8.6 0-15.5 6.9-15.5 15.5v0v376.5v0c0 9.9 8.1 18 18 18h233v0c9.9 0 18 8.1 18 18v549.5c0 9.9-8.1 18-18 18v0h-237c-6.9 0-12.5 5.6-12.5 12.5v0v381v0c0 9.1 7.4 16.5 16.5 16.5h233v0c9.9 0 18 8.1 18 18v681.9c0 53-43 96-96 96v0c-53 0-96 43-96 96v139.6  
            " />
      </path>
    </defs>
    <use href="#pathTmpl" stroke-width="0.25%" stroke-dasharray="0" stroke="#ccc"></use>
    <use id="stroke" href="#pathTmpl" stroke-dasharray="0 100000" stroke-width="0.25%" stroke="red"></use>
  
  <circle id="circle" cy="0" cx="0" r="0.5%" fill="green" fill-opacity="0.5"></circle>
  </svg>
```

### How it works

#### 1. Measure path and save data to a lookup

[`getPointAtLength()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGeometryElement/getPointAtLength) isn't per se slow but quite **expensive when called hundreds or thousands of times**.
We should avoid calling it again and again if we can reuse point coordinates for further processing and also avoid unnecessarily detailed sample point intervals (e.g. iterating by +1 length unit - as a path can easily be > 10 0000 units long).

Therefore, we calculate coordinates at equidistant sample points and save length, x and y to a lookup object.
We can use this lookup later to find a suitable length based on the target x/y coordinates.

#### 2. Tolerance threshold

We need to define an error tolerance because we most likely don't have the exact coordinates.
In the above example we return an "on-point" length if

- both xTarget/xLookup and yTarget/yLookup diffs are below tolerance = 10 user units
- *OR* xTarget/xLookup diff is below threshold and yTarget/yLookup diff is smaller tolerance * 2

The function will stop once it found a length/coordinate match within the defined tolerance - subsequent matches are ignored.

It is an arbitrary tolerance threshold. For a better accuracy you can decrease the tolerance and increase the number of sample points (currently 500 – pathlength ~ 10000 units)

You may also combine this function with [`isPointInStroke()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGeometryElement/isPointInStroke) to exclude off-path coordinates beforehand. Albeit this may be more expensive than a sloppy x/y coordinate diff check.

##### Main challenge: point-to-length relation

Although we can quite efficiently calculate many point coordinates deploying the appropriate formula for lines/polylines/polygons (linear interpolation – LERP) and quadratic or cubic bézier curves (De Casteljau algorithm) – we can't easily relate these points to actual lengths when it comes to béziers. See also ["Finding points on curves in HTML 5 2d Canvas context"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3570309/finding-points-on-curves-in-html-5-2d-canvas-context/#76773275) and [Primer on Bézier Curves §24 Arc length](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#arclength)

So the natively supported `getPointAtlength()` method already has to apply some complex calculations for a decent approximation – a native  `lengthAtPoint()` method would be a potential performance killer.

---

### Alternatives to native `getPointAtLength()` for better performance

There are JS libraries developed mainly to provide `getTotalLength()` and `getPointAtLength()` functionality in headless or virtual DOM environments such as node.js or react e.g. [svg-path-properties](https://github.com/rveciana/svg-path-properties).
In fact these "emulations" can often provide a better performance if you need to calculate > 100 points.

svg-path-properties for instance reads important path metrics once

```js
const properties = new path.svgPathProperties("M0,100 Q50,-50 100,100 T200,100");
```

and generates subsequent points based on this data

```js
const point = properties.getPointAtLength(200);
```

Generating many points this way is significantly faster than running native `getPointAtLength()` – as the latter will start from scratch each time we call it (parse path data, measure segment lengths etc).

The above example generating 500 sample points at length via native method can easily take more than 200ms  whereas svg-path-properties would need ~ 5–10ms (depending on your browser and device)

##### Example 2: pointAtlength() altenative

The following example is based on my [own experimental path length script](https://github.com/herrstrietzel/svg-getpointatlength/) which shares a lot of concepts with svg-path-properties.

We can easily increase accuracy by calculating 10 000 samples to improve length-at-point accuracy – albeit ~ 2000–5000 should be enough and unnecessarily high precision will also introduce higher memory usage. All in all – we need to find a balance between accuracy and performance.

```js
const svg = document.querySelector("svg");
const pathTmpl = document.getElementById("pathTmpl");
const strokePath = document.getElementById("stroke");

// steps for pathlength lookup
let precision = 10000;
let tolerance = 10;

// get pathLength alternative
t0 = performance.now()
// lookup for path length calculations
let lengthLookup = getPathLengthLookup(pathTmpl.getAttribute('d'))

// lookup for point at length calculations
let pointAtLengthLookup = getPointAtLengthLookup(lengthLookup, precision)

t1 = performance.now()
t2 = t1 - t0
console.log('pathLength alternative:', precision, 'sample points', t2, 'ms')


document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  // cursor point
  let pt = new DOMPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY);

  // update cursor
  let ptSvg = screenToSVG(svg, pt);
  circle.setAttribute("cx", ptSvg.x);
  circle.setAttribute("cy", ptSvg.y);

  // update length
  let lengthAtPoint = getLengthAtPoint(pointAtLengthLookup, ptSvg);

  // demo illustration: change dasharray
  if (lengthAtPoint) {
    strokePath.setAttribute(
      "stroke-dasharray",
      `${lengthAtPoint} ${lengthLookup.totalLength}`
    );
  }
});


function getLengthAtPoint(lengthLookup, pt) {
  let lengthAtPoint = 0;
  let {
    lengthArr,
    yArr,
    xArr,
    pathLength
  } = lengthLookup;


  // find length
  let found = false;

  for (let i = 0; i < yArr.length && !found; i++) {
    let x = xArr[i];
    let y = yArr[i];

    // compare diviations
    let diffX = Math.abs(pt.x - x);
    let diffY = Math.abs(pt.y - y);
    let diffMin = Math.min(diffX, diffY)
    let diffMax = Math.max(diffX, diffY)
    let diffTolerance = (tolerance - diffMax);


    // simple average diff
    let diff = (diffX + diffY) / 2;

    // add tolerance threshold
    let maxDiffRat = 1.5
    if (
      diff <= tolerance ||
      (diffX <= tolerance && diffY <= tolerance * maxDiffRat) ||
      (diffY <= tolerance && diffX <= tolerance * maxDiffRat)
    ) {

      // nearest length with close x/y coordinates
      let length = lengthArr[i];

      // interpolate length based on length deviation
      let lengthPrev = lengthArr[i - 1] ? lengthArr[i - 1] : length;
      lengthAtPoint = (lengthArr[i]) + (diffMax)

      // stop loop
      found = true;
    }
  }
  return lengthAtPoint;
}


/**
 * create lookup containing lengths and 
 * coordinates at equidistant
 */
function getPointAtLengthLookup(lengthLookup, precision = 100) {
  //create pathlength lookup
  let pathLength = lengthLookup.totalLength;
  let lengthAtPointLookup = {
    yArr: [],
    xArr: [],
    lengthArr: [],
    pathLength: pathLength
  };

  // sample point to calculate Y at pathLengths
  let step = Math.ceil(pathLength / precision);

  for (let l = 0; l < pathLength; l += step) {
    //let pt = SVGToScreen(svg, path.getPointAtLength(l));
    let pt = lengthLookup.getPointAtLength(l);
    lengthAtPointLookup.xArr.push(pt.x);
    lengthAtPointLookup.yArr.push(pt.y);
    lengthAtPointLookup.lengthArr.push(l);
  }
  return lengthAtPointLookup;
}

/** Based on @Paul LeBeau's answer
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48343436/how-to-convert-svg-element-coordinates-to-screen-coordinates#48354404
 */
function SVGToScreen(svg, pt) {
  let p = new DOMPoint(pt.x, pt.y);
  p = p.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM());
  return p;
}

function screenToSVG(svg, pt) {
  let p = new DOMPoint(pt.x, pt.y);
  return p.matrixTransform(svg.getScreenCTM().inverse());
}
```

```css
svg {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/svg-getpointatlength@1.0.5/getPointAtLengthLookup.js"></script>


<svg width="543" height="7907" viewBox="0 0 543 7907">
        <defs>
            <path fill="none" id="pathTmpl" d="M125.5 1v0c0 78.2 63.4 141.5 141.5 141.5h126.9c25.9 0 51.4 6.9 73.9 19.8v0c45.9 26.5 74.2 75.4 74.2 128.4v22.9l-2.2 20.1c-5.7 53.2-40.2 99-89.8 119.1l-25.3 10.2c-5.1 2.1-9.6 5.3-13.1 9.5v0c-5.2 6.1-8.1 13.9-8.1 22v9.7v0c0 12.8-10.4 23.3-23.3 23.3h-368.7c-5.8 0-10.5 4.7-10.5 10.5v0v405.5v0c0 5.8 4.7 10.5 10.5 10.5h378v0c7.7 0 14 6.3 14 14v384.3v762.9c0 34.2-27.8 62-62 62v0c-34.2 0-62 27.7-62 62v180.8c0 7.2-5.8 13-13 13v0h-249.5c-6.6 0-12 5.4-12 12v0v400v0c0 8.8 7.2 16 16 16h245.5v0c7.2 0 13 5.8 13 13v1129.6c0 53.9-43.8 97.7-97.7 97.7v0c-54 0-97.8 43.8-97.8 97.8v133.4v0c0 3.3 2.7 6 6 6h92.5v0c3.3 0 6 2.7 6 6v417.5c0 2.8-2.2 5-5 5v0h-92.5c-3.9 0-7 3.1-7 7v0v331.7c0 77.8 63.1 141 141 141h36.2c57.9 0 104.8 46.9 104.8 104.8v0v104.5v0c0 7.5-6 13.5-13.5 13.5h-240c-8.6 0-15.5 6.9-15.5 15.5v0v376.5v0c0 9.9 8.1 18 18 18h233v0c9.9 0 18 8.1 18 18v549.5c0 9.9-8.1 18-18 18v0h-237c-6.9 0-12.5 5.6-12.5 12.5v0v381v0c0 9.1 7.4 16.5 16.5 16.5h233v0c9.9 0 18 8.1 18 18v681.9c0 53-43 96-96 96v0c-53 0-96 43-96 96v139.6  
                " />
            </path>
        </defs>
        <use href="#pathTmpl" stroke-width="0.25%" stroke-dasharray="0" stroke="#ccc"></use>
        <use id="stroke" href="#pathTmpl" stroke-dasharray="0 100000" stroke-width="0.25%" stroke="red"></use>

        <circle id="circle" cy="0" cx="0" r="0.5%" fill="green" fill-opacity="0.5"></circle>
    </svg>
```

##### Alternative path length libraries

- [rveciana's "svg-path-properties"](https://github.com/rveciana/svg-path-properties)
- [Kaiido's "path2D-inspection"](https://github.com/Kaiido/path2D-inspection) – interesting if you're foremost working with canvas

Comment: Thanks for the publicity, though I must note that my project is actually using the same *svg-path-properties* lib for the length calculations, so it's really just useful to get the path string from a normally opaque Path2D object (which may be useful even for non canvas users, since it's also available in Workers contrarily to <path>).

Comment: @Kaiido: There's another significant benefit to using your library/prototype: rveciana's "svg-path-properties" currently struggles with minified Arcto notations concatenating largeArc, sweep flag and final x-coordinates (e.g. ` A 5 10 45 1040 20`), as well as elliptical arcs - mainly due to issues in the path data parser and arc parameterisation scripts used (I already filed this bug). You probably haven't encountered these issues since your parser and arc parametrization is based on Vitali Puzrin's svg-path functions.

Comment: Yes, I do simplify the path data before I give it to svg-path-library indeed (canvas parametrization is quite different than svg's one). Still I should probably check that I indeed avoid this issue. Thanks for letting me know.

Comment: @Kaiido: BTW. I've created a [test bed](https://codepen.io/herrstrietzel/pen/WNWRroO) with some tricky example paths challenging the path-properties  parsing.

Comment: Awesome. That almost makes me want to start working on perfs. I guess we could memoize here and there and save a couple ms for the getPointAtLength in a loop test, which could be useful, but I never meant that project to be a fast alternative to others and the current results are actually quite satisfying (and more importantly I terribly lack time to work on that :-P)